# How to use two data ("autocomplete") i.e renderitem and resize together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

```
$(".someClassWithMultipleItemsOnDOM").autocomplete({

        minLength:2,
        source .....(ajax call)
        .....   
}).focus( function() {
            /*some code*/

        })
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
/*render item for making search text bold*/

};
.data("autocomplete")._resizeMenu = function () {
        /*resize code to set the size of autocosearch drop down box*/
        };
```

I recives the error at resize menu line that there is syntax error ,, is there any way too use both function together. In similar manner.

Comment: The syntax error is because the second `.data` has no object before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both _renderItem and _resizeMenu like this.

```
  var tag = $("#domId").autocomplete({
              source:...........
   });
  tag.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
              /* Your code*/
   };
  tag.data("autocomplete")._resizeMenu = function () {
              /* Your code*/
   };
```

Take a look at this site [JQFAQ](http://jqfaq.com/) , it will be more useful for jQuery developers.